# Theming of custom Fluent React Component Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluent

I am working to use the MS Fluent widgets in an RShiny React application.  Things are working fine (at least I think) with the exception of the theming of the label element.  When I use an existing MS Fluent Reactive element, such as a TextField, the label shows up with a font weight medium (600).  I would like a similar label for my custom component.  I have added a Label field into my custom component but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it with the correct look and feel of the built-in components.

I have put together a CodePen for this at https://codepen.io/justacec/pen/gOBBbdN

This CodePen shows the issue at the bottom.

I recognize that the TextField label has a class assigned to it that is `root-132` (might be different on your browser) and the styling is carried through on that CSS class.  But I am not sure how to get that internally generated class connected to the label for my custom component?

What do I need to do here to get the label in my custom component to match the built-in label styling?